Fix PostScript file in Java (Missing %%EOF marker)
I have an Fortran application that can output PostScript files. When trying to read in the files using the ghost4j library, I get the following error
ERROR: %%EOF not found. File is not well-formed.

If I try to add the end of file marker to the file using echo %%EOF >> plotfile.001, I then get the following error:
ERROR: PostScript document is not valid

The strange thing is, I can see and open both files (old and modified) fine in Ubuntu Document Viewer. The contents of the file are essentially (header and end) are (before I concatenate the %%EOF to the end):
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Creator: HGRAPH
%%Title: PLOTFILE
%%CreationDate:
initgraphics
.24 .24 scale 2396 93 translate 90 rotate
/yo 17.71654 def
/mt {moveto} def
/lt {lineto} def
/rm {rmoveto} def
/rl {rlineto} def
/np {newpath} def
/cp {closepath} def
/st {stroke} def
/ef {eofill} def
/sg {setgray} def
/sc {setrgbcolor} def
/sk {setcmykcolor} def
/pc { moveto rotate dup stringwidth pop
2 div dup neg yo neg rmoveto exch show
yo rmoveto rotate } def
/fs { currentfont exch makefont setfont
/yo exch yo mul def } def
1 setlinejoin 1 setlinecap 1 setlinewidth
/Courier
findfont [   53.149 0 0   53.149 0 0 ]
makefont setfont
 0.5000 [  0.5000 0 0  0.5000 0 0 ] fs
   0 ( )   0    2623    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2641    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2659    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2676    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2694    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2712    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2729    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2747    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2765    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2783    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2800    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2818    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2836    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2854    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2871    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2889    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2907    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2924    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2942    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2960    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2978    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    2995    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    3013    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    3031    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    3048    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    3066    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    3084    2305 pc
   0 (H)   0    3102    2305 pc
   0 (G)   0    3119    2305 pc
   0 (R)   0    3137    2305 pc
   0 (A)   0    3155    2305 pc
   0 (P)   0    3172    2305 pc
   0 (H)   0    3190    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0    3208    2305 pc
   0 (v)   0    3226    2305 pc
   0 (2)   0    3243    2305 pc
   0 (1)   0    3261    2305 pc
   0 (/)   0    3279    2305 pc
   0 (2)   0    3296    2305 pc
   0 (3)   0    3314    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0       9    2305 pc
   0 (-)   0      27    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0      44    2305 pc
   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (P)   0     204    2305 pc
   0 (�)   0     221    2305 pc
   0 (S)   0     239    2305 pc
   0 ()   0     257    2305 pc
   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (   0 (P)   0     487    2305 pc
   0 (�)   0     505    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     523    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     540    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     558    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     576    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     594    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     611    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     629    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     647    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     664    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     682    2305 pc
   0 ( )   0     700    2305 pc
st
np
 2939 358 mt
 -2363 0 rl
st
np
 576 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
 2.0000 [  2.0000 0 0  2.0000 0 0 ] fs
   0 ( )   0     506     234 pc
   0 (0)   0     541     234 pc
   0 (.)   0     576     234 pc
   0 (0)   0     612     234 pc
st
np
 695 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 813 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0     742     234 pc
   0 (0)   0     777     234 pc
   0 (.)   0     813     234 pc
   0 (1)   0     848     234 pc
st
np
 931 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 1049 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0     978     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    1013     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    1049     234 pc
   0 (2)   0    1084     234 pc
st
np
 1167 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 1285 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0    1214     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    1250     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    1285     234 pc
   0 (3)   0    1321     234 pc
st
np
 1403 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 1521 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0    1450     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    1486     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    1521     234 pc
   0 (4)   0    1557     234 pc
st
np
 1639 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 1758 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0    1687     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    1722     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    1758     234 pc
   0 (5)   0    1793     234 pc
st
np
 1876 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 1994 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0    1923     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    1958     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    1994     234 pc
   0 (6)   0    2029     234 pc
st
np
 2112 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 2230 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0    2159     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    2195     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    2230     234 pc
   0 (7)   0    2265     234 pc
st
np
 2348 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 2466 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0    2395     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    2431     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    2466     234 pc
   0 (8)   0    2502     234 pc
st
np
 2584 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 2702 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0    2632     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    2667     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    2702     234 pc
   0 (9)   0    2738     234 pc
st
np
 2821 358 mt
 0 -17 rl
st
np
 2939 358 mt
 0 -35 rl
   0 ( )   0    2868     234 pc
   0 (1)   0    2903     234 pc
   0 (.)   0    2939     234 pc
   0 (0)   0    2974     234 pc
st
np
 576 2130 mt
 0 -1772 rl
st
np
 576 358 mt
 -35 0 rl
   0 ( )   0     364     350 pc
   0 (0)   0     399     350 pc
   0 (.)   0     435     350 pc
   0 (0)   0     470     350 pc
st
np
 576 506 mt
 -17 0 rl
st
np
 576 654 mt
 -35 0 rl
   0 ( )   0     364     645 pc
   0 (0)   0     399     645 pc
   0 (.)   0     435     645 pc
   0 (1)   0     470     645 pc
st
np
 576 801 mt
 -17 0 rl
st
np
 576 949 mt
 -35 0 rl
   0 ( )   0     364     940 pc
   0 (0)   0     399     940 pc
   0 (.)   0     435     940 pc
   0 (2)   0     470     940 pc
st
np
 576 1097 mt
 -17 0 rl
st
np
 576 1244 mt
 -35 0 rl
   0 ( )   0     364    1235 pc
   0 (0)   0     399    1235 pc
   0 (.)   0     435    1235 pc
   0 (3)   0     470    1235 pc
st
np
 576 1392 mt
 -17 0 rl
st
np
 576 1539 mt
 -35 0 rl
   0 ( )   0     364    1531 pc
   0 (0)   0     399    1531 pc
   0 (.)   0     435    1531 pc
   0 (4)   0     470    1531 pc
st
np
 576 1687 mt
 -17 0 rl
st
np
 576 1835 mt
 -35 0 rl
   0 ( )   0     364    1826 pc
   0 (0)   0     399    1826 pc
   0 (.)   0     435    1826 pc
   0 (5)   0     470    1826 pc
st
np
 576 1982 mt
 -17 0 rl
st
np
 576 2130 mt
 -35 0 rl
   0 ( )   0     364    2121 pc
   0 (0)   0     399    2121 pc
   0 (.)   0     435    2121 pc
   0 (6)   0     470    2121 pc
   0 (o)   0     576     358 pc
   0 (o)   0     577     375 pc
   0 (o)   0     577     393 pc
   0 (o)   0     578     411 pc
   0 (o)   0     579     428 pc
   0 (o)   0     580     445 pc
   0 (o)   0     582     462 pc
   0 (o)   0     584     479 pc
   0 (o)   0     586     497 pc
   0 (o)   0     588     515 pc
   0 (o)   0     591     534 pc
   0 (o)   0     594     553 pc
   0 (o)   0     598     573 pc
   0 (o)   0     601     593 pc
   0 (o)   0     605     613 pc
   0 (o)   0     609     634 pc
   0 (o)   0     614     655 pc
   0 (o)   0     619     676 pc
   0 (o)   0     624     698 pc
   0 (o)   0     629     720 pc
   0 (o)   0     635     743 pc
   0 (o)   0     641     766 pc
   0 (o)   0     647     789 pc
   0 (o)   0     653     813 pc
   0 (o)   0     660     836 pc
   0 (o)   0     667     860 pc
   0 (o)   0     675     885 pc
   0 (o)   0     682     909 pc
   0 (o)   0     690     933 pc
   0 (o)   0     698     956 pc
   0 (o)   0     706     980 pc
   0 (o)   0     715    1003 pc
   0 (o)   0     724    1025 pc
   0 (o)   0     733    1047 pc
   0 (o)   0     743    1070 pc
   0 (o)   0     752    1092 pc
   0 (o)   0     762    1114 pc
   0 (o)   0     772    1137 pc
   0 (o)   0     783    1159 pc
   0 (o)   0     793    1182 pc
   0 (o)   0     804    1204 pc
   0 (o)   0     815    1227 pc
   0 (o)   0     827    1250 pc
   0 (o)   0     838    1272 pc
   0 (o)   0     850    1295 pc
   0 (o)   0     862    1317 pc
   0 (o)   0     874    1339 pc
   0 (o)   0     887    1361 pc
   0 (o)   0     900    1383 pc
   0 (o)   0     913    1406 pc
   0 (o)   0     926    1427 pc
   0 (o)   0     939    1449 pc
   0 (o)   0     953    1470 pc
   0 (o)   0     966    1491 pc
   0 (o)   0     980    1512 pc
   0 (o)   0     994    1532 pc
   0 (o)   0    1009    1552 pc
   0 (o)   0    1023    1572 pc
   0 (o)   0    1038    1591 pc
   0 (o)   0    1053    1611 pc
   0 (o)   0    1068    1629 pc
   0 (o)   0    1083    1648 pc
   0 (o)   0    1098    1666 pc
   0 (o)   0    1114    1683 pc
   0 (o)   0    1130    1701 pc
   0 (o)   0    1146    1717 pc
   0 (o)   0    1162    1733 pc
   0 (o)   0    1178    1749 pc
   0 (o)   0    1194    1764 pc
   0 (o)   0    1211    1779 pc
   0 (o)   0    1227    1793 pc
   0 (o)   0    1244    1807 pc
   0 (o)   0    1261    1820 pc
   0 (o)   0    1278    1833 pc
   0 (o)   0    1295    1845 pc
   0 (o)   0    1312    1856 pc
   0 (o)   0    1329    1867 pc
   0 (o)   0    1347    1877 pc
   0 (o)   0    1364    1887 pc
   0 (o)   0    1382    1896 pc
   0 (o)   0    1400    1905 pc
   0 (o)   0    1418    1913 pc
   0 (o)   0    1435    1920 pc
   0 (o)   0    1453    1927 pc
   0 (o)   0    1471    1933 pc
   0 (o)   0    1490    1938 pc
   0 (o)   0    1508    1943 pc
   0 (o)   0    1526    1947 pc
   0 (o)   0    1544    1951 pc
   0 (o)   0    1563    1954 pc
   0 (o)   0    1581    1956 pc
   0 (o)   0    1600    1957 pc
   0 (o)   0    1618    1958 pc
   0 (o)   0    1637    1959 pc
   0 (o)   0    1655    1958 pc
   0 (o)   0    1674    1957 pc
   0 (o)   0    1692    1956 pc
   0 (o)   0    1711    1954 pc
   0 (o)   0    1730    1951 pc
   0 (o)   0    1748    1947 pc
   0 (o)   0    1767    1943 pc
   0 (o)   0    1786    1938 pc
   0 (o)   0    1804    1933 pc
   0 (o)   0    1823    1927 pc
   0 (o)   0    1841    1920 pc
   0 (o)   0    1860    1913 pc
   0 (o)   0    1879    1905 pc
   0 (o)   0    1897    1897 pc
   0 (o)   0    1916    1888 pc
   0 (o)   0    1934    1879 pc
   0 (o)   0    1952    1869 pc
   0 (o)   0    1971    1858 pc
   0 (o)   0    1989    1847 pc
   0 (o)   0    2007    1835 pc
   0 (o)   0    2026    1823 pc
   0 (o)   0    2044    1810 pc
   0 (o)   0    2062    1797 pc
   0 (o)   0    2080    1784 pc
   0 (o)   0    2098    1770 pc
   0 (o)   0    2115    1755 pc
   0 (o)   0    2133    1740 pc
   0 (o)   0    2151    1725 pc
   0 (o)   0    2168    1709 pc
   0 (o)   0    2186    1693 pc
   0 (o)   0    2203    1676 pc
   0 (o)   0    2220    1660 pc
   0 (o)   0    2237    1642 pc
   0 (o)   0    2254    1625 pc
   0 (o)   0    2271    1607 pc
   0 (o)   0    2288    1588 pc
   0 (o)   0    2305    1570 pc
   0 (o)   0    2321    1551 pc
   0 (o)   0    2337    1532 pc
   0 (o)   0    2354    1513 pc
   0 (o)   0    2370    1493 pc
   0 (o)   0    2385    1474 pc
   0 (o)   0    2401    1454 pc
   0 (o)   0    2417    1434 pc
   0 (o)   0    2432    1414 pc
   0 (o)   0    2447    1393 pc
   0 (o)   0    2462    1373 pc
   0 (o)   0    2477    1352 pc
   0 (o)   0    2492    1331 pc
   0 (o)   0    2506    1311 pc
   0 (o)   0    2521    1290 pc
   0 (o)   0    2535    1269 pc
   0 (o)   0    2549    1249 pc
   0 (o)   0    2563    1228 pc
   0 (o)   0    2576    1207 pc
   0 (o)   0    2589    1186 pc
   0 (o)   0    2603    1166 pc
   0 (o)   0    2615    1145 pc
   0 (o)   0    2628    1125 pc
   0 (o)   0    2641    1105 pc
   0 (o)   0    2653    1084 pc
   0 (o)   0    2665    1064 pc
   0 (o)   0    2677    1045 pc
   0 (o)   0    2688    1025 pc
   0 (o)   0    2700    1005 pc
   0 (o)   0    2711     986 pc
   0 (o)   0    2722     967 pc
   0 (o)   0    2732     948 pc
   0 (o)   0    2743     930 pc
   0 (o)   0    2753     912 pc
   0 (o)   0    2763     894 pc
   0 (o)   0    2773     876 pc
   0 (o)   0    2782     859 pc
   0 (o)   0    2791     842 pc
   0 (o)   0    2800     826 pc
   0 (o)   0    2809     810 pc
   0 (o)   0    2817     794 pc
   0 (o)   0    2825     778 pc
   0 (o)   0    2833     763 pc
   0 (o)   0    2841     749 pc
   0 (o)   0    2848     735 pc
   0 (o)   0    2855     721 pc
   0 (o)   0    2862     707 pc
   0 (o)   0    2868     691 pc
   0 (o)   0    2874     674 pc
   0 (o)   0    2880     657 pc
   0 (o)   0    2886     639 pc
   0 (o)   0    2891     622 pc
   0 (o)   0    2896     605 pc
   0 (o)   0    2901     588 pc
   0 (o)   0    2906     571 pc
   0 (o)   0    2910     554 pc
   0 (o)   0    2914     538 pc
   0 (o)   0    2918     523 pc
   0 (o)   0    2921     507 pc
   0 (o)   0    2924     493 pc
   0 (o)   0    2927     478 pc
   0 (o)   0    2929     464 pc
   0 (o)   0    2931     451 pc
   0 (o)   0    2933     438 pc
   0 (o)   0    2935     426 pc
   0 (o)   0    2936     413 pc
   0 (o)   0    2937     400 pc
   0 (o)   0    2938     385 pc
   0 (o)   0    2939     369 pc
   0 (o)   0    2939     358 pc
st
np
 576 358 mt
 0 0 rl
 1 17 rl
 0 18 rl
 1 18 rl
 1 17 rl
 1 17 rl
 2 17 rl
 2 17 rl
 2 18 rl
 2 18 rl
 3 19 rl
 3 19 rl
 4 20 rl
 3 20 rl
 4 20 rl
 4 21 rl
 5 21 rl
 5 21 rl
 5 22 rl
 5 22 rl
 6 23 rl
 6 23 rl
 6 23 rl
 6 24 rl
 7 23 rl
 7 24 rl
 8 25 rl
 7 24 rl
 8 24 rl
 8 23 rl
 8 24 rl
 9 23 rl
 9 22 rl
 9 22 rl
 10 23 rl
 9 22 rl
 10 22 rl
 10 23 rl
 11 22 rl
 10 23 rl
 11 22 rl
 11 23 rl
 12 23 rl
 11 22 rl
 12 23 rl
 12 22 rl
 12 22 rl
 13 22 rl
 13 22 rl
 13 23 rl
 13 21 rl
 13 22 rl
 14 21 rl
 13 21 rl
 14 21 rl
 14 20 rl
 15 20 rl
 14 20 rl
 15 19 rl
 15 20 rl
 15 18 rl
 15 19 rl
 15 18 rl
 16 17 rl
 16 18 rl
 16 16 rl
 16 16 rl
 16 16 rl
 16 15 rl
 17 15 rl
 16 14 rl
 17 14 rl
 17 13 rl
 17 13 rl
 17 12 rl
 17 11 rl
 17 11 rl
 18 10 rl
 17 10 rl
 18 9 rl
 18 9 rl
 18 8 rl
 17 7 rl
 18 7 rl
 18 6 rl
 19 5 rl
 18 5 rl
 18 4 rl
 18 4 rl
 19 3 rl
 18 2 rl
 19 1 rl
 18 1 rl
 19 1 rl
 18 -1 rl
 19 -1 rl
 18 -1 rl
 19 -2 rl
 19 -3 rl
 18 -4 rl
 19 -4 rl
 19 -5 rl
 18 -5 rl
 19 -6 rl
 18 -7 rl
 19 -7 rl
 19 -8 rl
 18 -8 rl
 19 -9 rl
 18 -9 rl
 18 -10 rl
 19 -11 rl
 18 -11 rl
 18 -12 rl
 19 -12 rl
 18 -13 rl
 18 -13 rl
 18 -13 rl
 18 -14 rl
 17 -15 rl
 18 -15 rl
 18 -15 rl
 17 -16 rl
 18 -16 rl
 17 -17 rl
 17 -16 rl
 17 -18 rl
 17 -17 rl
 17 -18 rl
 17 -19 rl
 17 -18 rl
 16 -19 rl
 16 -19 rl
 17 -19 rl
 16 -20 rl
 15 -19 rl
 16 -20 rl
 16 -20 rl
 15 -20 rl
 15 -21 rl
 15 -20 rl
 15 -21 rl
 15 -21 rl
 14 -20 rl
 15 -21 rl
 14 -21 rl
 14 -20 rl
 14 -21 rl
 13 -21 rl
 13 -21 rl
 14 -20 rl
 12 -21 rl
 13 -20 rl
 13 -20 rl
 12 -21 rl
 12 -20 rl
 12 -19 rl
 11 -20 rl
 12 -20 rl
 11 -19 rl
 11 -19 rl
 10 -19 rl
 11 -18 rl
 10 -18 rl
 10 -18 rl
 10 -18 rl
 9 -17 rl
 9 -17 rl
 9 -16 rl
 9 -16 rl
 8 -16 rl
 8 -16 rl
 8 -15 rl
 8 -14 rl
 7 -14 rl
 7 -14 rl
 7 -14 rl
 6 -16 rl
 6 -17 rl
 6 -17 rl
 6 -18 rl
 5 -17 rl
 5 -17 rl
 5 -17 rl
 5 -17 rl
 4 -17 rl
 4 -16 rl
 4 -15 rl
 3 -16 rl
 3 -14 rl
 3 -15 rl
 2 -14 rl
 2 -13 rl
 2 -13 rl
 2 -12 rl
 1 -13 rl
 1 -13 rl
 1 -15 rl
 1 -16 rl
 0 -11 rl
   0 (X)   0    1527     128 pc
   0 ( )   0    1563     128 pc
   0 ( )   0    1598     128 pc
   0 (C)   0    1634     128 pc
   0 (O)   0    1669     128 pc
   0 (O)   0    1704     128 pc
   0 (R)   0    1740     128 pc
   0 (D)   0    1775     128 pc
   0 (I)   0    1811     128 pc
   0 (N)   0    1846     128 pc
   0 (A)   0    1882     128 pc
   0 (T)   0    1917     128 pc
   0 (E)   0    1952     128 pc
   0 ( )   0    1988     128 pc
 -90 (T)  90     240     908 pc
 -90 (A)  90     240     943 pc
 -90 (N)  90     240     978 pc
 -90 (G)  90     240    1014 pc
 -90 (E)  90     240    1049 pc
 -90 (N)  90     240    1085 pc
 -90 (T)  90     240    1120 pc
 -90 (I)  90     240    1156 pc
 -90 (A)  90     240    1191 pc
 -90 (L)  90     240    1226 pc
 -90 ( )  90     240    1262 pc
 -90 (T)  90     240    1297 pc
 -90 (H)  90     240    1333 pc
 -90 (I)  90     240    1368 pc
 -90 (C)  90     240    1404 pc
 -90 (K)  90     240    1439 pc
 -90 (N)  90     240    1475 pc
 -90 (E)  90     240    1510 pc
 -90 (S)  90     240    1545 pc
 -90 (S)  90     240    1581 pc
 1.5152 [  1.5152 0 0  1.5152 0 0 ] fs
   0 (T)   0    1194     444 pc
   0 (H)   0    1248     444 pc
   0 (I)   0    1301     444 pc
   0 (C)   0    1355     444 pc
   0 (K)   0    1409     444 pc
   0 (N)   0    1462     444 pc
   0 (E)   0    1516     444 pc
   0 (S)   0    1570     444 pc
   0 (S)   0    1623     444 pc
   0 ( )   0    1677     444 pc
   0 (D)   0    1731     444 pc
   0 (I)   0    1784     444 pc
   0 (S)   0    1838     444 pc
   0 (T)   0    1892     444 pc
   0 (R)   0    1945     444 pc
   0 (I)   0    1999     444 pc
   0 (B)   0    2053     444 pc
   0 (U)   0    2107     444 pc
   0 (T)   0    2160     444 pc
   0 (I)   0    2214     444 pc
   0 (O)   0    2268     444 pc
   0 (N)   0    2321     444 pc
stroke
showpage

Essentially what I would like to do is be able to load the .ps file, convert it to an image format (say .png) and then display / embed it in a Swing app. It seems only ghost4j is available for Java implementations, so I was wondering whether anyone had any additional knowledge or had seen something like this before or how to "fix" the file?
The Java code I am running is:
public class SimpleRendererExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
             // load PS document
             PSDocument document = new PSDocument();
             document.load(new File("plotfile.001"));

             // create renderer
             SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();

             // set resolution (in DPI)
             renderer.setResolution(300);

             // render
             List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);

             // write images to files to disk as PNG
             try
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
                 {
                     ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) images.get(i), "png", new File((i + 1) + ".png"));
                 }
              } catch (IOException e)
              {
                  System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
              }
          } catch (Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
          }
    }
}


It might be useful if you were to give us a valid file (apart from %%EOF) Of course, your redirection command would currently leave you with showpage%%EOF which is probably invalid

hmm, %%EOF technically is a postscript comment used possibly for DSC (postscript document structuring conventions). Normally ghostscript would not look at it but why would ghost4j? Does your ghost4j docs give a hint as how to use plain ghostscript?

To clarify, I have also used a hexeditor to add the %%EOF (on a new line) and still get the same errors. The ghost4j project is not under active development anymore and I havent found anything thats helpful yet unfortunately. I have managed now to use gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf plotfile.001 which gives me a valid PDF file (which also incidently includes an %%EOF on the last line)

@g00se Thanks for the comment ... I've updated the question with the full .ps file contents ...

GPL Ghostscript 10.00.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 is what I get, with or without %%EOF though a pdf (of sorts) is created.

Prepare for a world of insanity. PostScript is Turing Complete.

The problematic lines seem to be those where (  is contained inside a ( .. ) (lines 72 and 76) string, escape those ( and I get some kind of PDF but I do not know if it is what you expected
